# Solutions to the wave equation on non orientable surfaces like a mobius strip

Tags: differential-equations, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Given a mobius strip, what do the solutions of the wave equation look like qualitatively?   How do they differ from solutions on the equivalent strip glued together as a cylinder?   Any refs, particularly to symmetry?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=t0D_YmZpTucC&pg=PA333

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: Well, say I'm trying to excite it with vibrations near the fundamental frequency of the corresponding orientable cylindrical surface.  Is the resonant frequency (eigenvalue) of the mobius strip shifted?   I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but you see what I'm imagining.

Comment: I guess to more specifically respond, the boundary conditions are free, with forcing at theta = 0, on a line orthogonal to the midline circle. 

Comment: Force is harmonic (sinusoidal), to be applied normal to the surface.

Comment: Then, a second set of boundry conditions of interest is where two sinusoidal forces are applied at two points P1 = (theta, width) = (0,1/2) and P2 = (0,-1/2), with the forces entirely out of phase (by a factor of pi), to generate a sort of rocking motion at theta = 0 

Comment: @Steve: somehow I interpret the question the OP asked to be solving the wave equation on $M\times \mathbb{R}$, where $M$ is the Mobius strip, as opposed to solving the wave equation for a non-time-orientable metric on $M$. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any solution to the wave equation on a Möbius strip lifts to a solution on its orientation double cover, which is a cylinder of equal width but twice the circumference.  In order for a solution on the cylinder to descend to the Möbius strip, it is necessary and sufficient that it be invariant under a certain order two symmetry.  If the cylinder has coordinates given by $[0,\pi a]$ in the free direction and $[0, 2\pi L]$ in the loop direction, then the solutions are linear combinations of products $AB$, where $A$ has the form $\cos (kn_a t)\cos(\frac{n_a}a x)$ or $\sin (kn_a t)\cos(\frac{n_a}a x)$, and $B$ has the form $\cos(kn_Lt)\cos(\frac{n_L}{L}y)$, $\sin(kn_Lt)\cos(\frac{n_L}{L}y)$, $\cos(kn_Lt)\sin(\frac{n_L}{L}y)$, or $\sin(kn_Lt)\sin(\frac{n_L}{L}y)$.  Here, $n_a$ and $n_L$ are nonnegative integers, and $k$ is a constant.  Invariance under the symmetry is equivalent to $n_a + n_L$ being an even number.  In contrast, solutions on the cylinder of the same dimensions correspond to solutions on the double cover such that only $n_L$ is even.

Comment: A surprising and lovely answer.  Can you say a little more about
a)  the order two symmetry 
b)  the proof that n_sub_a + n_sub_L must be even, 
or refer us to a reference?

Comment: The order two symmetry is defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (\pi a - x, \pi L + y)$, where $x$ is the coordinate in the free direction, $y$ is the coordinate in the loop direction, and the $y$ coordinates are considered modulo $2 \pi L$.  The proof of invariance comes from examining the eigenfunctions I listed above, and seeing which ones are unchanged under the transformation.  This reduces to the fact that cosine and sine get multiplied by $-1$ when the domain is translated by $\pi$.  I do not know a reference.

Answer (score 4):

The following [paper](http://physics.bgu.ac.il/~dcohen/ARCHIVE/mbs_PRB.pdf) by: Kousuke Yakubo,Yshai Avishai,and Doron Cohen describes in section II the solution of the Helmholtz equation on a flat rectangular surface having the topology of a Mobius strip. The solution is given in terms of the admissible wave numbers.

Comment: While not directly on point (answers a slightly different question, with different boundary conditions), this suggestion materially advances my understanding of the subject.  I would greatly appreciate further contributions by others as well.